# FFmpeg: create data streams in MP4 container

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, quicktime, webm, matroska

Is there a way to make FFmpeg create data streams in MP4 or Quicktime (.mov) containers? I have tried `-attach ...` (works fine for Matroska containers, but not MP4/MOV) or `-codec bin_data`, but to no avail.

`-attach ...` technically creates streams with codec type "attachment", which are different from data streams. And while FFmpeg isn't smart enough to directly create data streams in containers where attachment streams aren't supported (ie. MP4), a two-step approach works:

```
ffmpeg -i <some media file> -attach <some data file> -metadata:s:2 mimetype=<data MIME type> -map 0:v -map 0:a -codec copy attached.mkv
ffmpeg -i attached.mkv -codec copy attached.mp4
```

The first command creates a Matroska file that contains a stream with `codec_type=attachment`. The second command then simply re-packages this into an MP4 container, turning the attachment stream into a data stream (`codec_type=data`). So the question is: could this be combined into a single step?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ffmpeg -i <some media file> -i file:<some data file> \
       -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:d -codec copy attached.mp4
```

Comment: Strangely enough, I get `Unknown input format: 'file'`. Not sure how this can be, `file` is (obviously) a protocol that's compiled into FFmpeg.

Comment: Interesting. How about if you use `-i file:datafile.bin` format?